# multiple object operators in one call

Tags: php, object, call, operator-keyword

Sorry,

Maybe this question already exists, but I couldn't find. I am quite new in PHP ... just I would need a bit explanation.

what means the next line, when we use many object operators in one call.

```
$variable = $this->any1->any2->any3->get_data(params);
```

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: but then, your example has no function call operators, so if that's to be taken literally, then it can't be method chaining, and it would just be bog-standard access of members in progressively nested objects.

Comment: Not exactly method chaining. That code only follows the object fields. Method chaning would be `$this->any1()->any2()->any3()`

Comment: Yes, any1, any2, any3 are not methods ... I suppose stdClasses, just I don't understand exactly how to read this.

Comment: Then the answer is obvious: you are accessing `this`'s field `any1`, then *its* field `any2`, then etc. If you know what one `->` operator does, you know what the others do.

Comment: Right, I glazed over all the missing parens... maybe thought it was a rushed typed out example. So, yeah, thats more of a huge object nest which caused mind-hurt following it all around to figure out exactly what its doing, as you have to find each assignment of which object is at what level... ?! Heh.

Comment: as the others said, it's a series of nested objects. `var_dump($this);` will show you (in a semi-visual way) the object's structure with all the nested objects and their properties.

Comment: OK ... still not clear ... we nested a bunch of objects ... and what does the method does end of the chain? It's not clear why we need to nest objects and then call a function? What's the connection between them? How will it be evaluated? Would be great a simple example. Sorry ... I'm straggling with understanding this.

Comment: _"It's not clear why we need to nest objects and then call a function?"_ You tell us! It's your example. We never **need** to do anything in any language; we do it if it serves a useful purpose. Well, that's the ideal world - whatever code prompted you to ask this question may or may not be useful. _"What's the connection between them? How will it be evaluated?"_ Exactly as it's written; each field will be accessed, then the method is called on the final one. Ultimately: if you don't know why someone would write code like this, then don't write it, and don't worry about it.

Comment: THX  underscore_d, helped a lot! FF

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
class A{
    private $any1; //a class B object

    public function __construct(){ $this->any1=new B(); }

    public function myMethod(){
        $variable=$this->any1->any2->any3->get_data('aParam'); //You are here
        var_dump($variable);
    }
}

class B{
    public $any2; //a class C object

    public function __construct(){ $this->any2=new C(); }
}

class C{
    public $any3; //a class D object

    public function __construct(){ $this->any3=new D(); }
}

class D{
    private $data=['aParam'=>'A content'];

    public function get_data($params){ //Here is what you want
        return $this->data[$params]; 
    }
}

$a=new A();
$a->myMethod(); //you'll see: string(9) "A content"
```

Avoid public attributes in class, use getters and setters (it's just shorter there).